# How can I persist user authentication after a token refresh in a React application using axios interceptors?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am currently using axios interceptors to refresh an expired access token and refresh token from the server, which are stored in localStorage and cookies respectively. However, after the new access token is generated, I get logged out from the application. I am also using cookies to store user roles, which are used to protect routes using react-router-dom.

I have tried different methods to fix this issue, but it still occurs. How can I ensure that the user stays authenticated after a token refresh in my React application?
Here is the code:

```
export default function useRefreshToken() {
  const refresh = async () => {
    // gets the refresh token from cookies
    const refresh_token = getRefreshToken();
    try {
      const response = await axios.post("/api/refresh", null, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${refresh_token}`,
        },
      });

      const accessToken = response.data.access_token;
      const refreshToken = response.data.refresh_token;

      console.log("New access token:", accessToken);
      console.log("New refresh token:", refreshToken);

      // sets the new access token and refresh token to localStorage and cookies
      setTokens(accessToken, refreshToken);

      return accessToken;

    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(error);
    }
  };
  return refresh;
}
```

Here is the axios interceptors code:

```
export default function useAxiosPrivate() {
  const refresh = useRefreshToken();
  
  useEffect(() => {

    const requestIntercept = axiosPrivate.interceptors.request.use(
      (config) => {
        const accessToken = getAccessToken();
        if (accessToken) {
          config.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
        }
        return config;
      },
      (error) => Promise.reject(error)
    );

    const responseIntercept = axiosPrivate.interceptors.response.use(
      (response) => response,
      async (error) => {
        const originalConfig = error?.config;
        if (error?.response?.status === 401 || 403  && !originalConfig?._retry) {
          originalConfig._retry = true;
          try {
            const newAccessToken = await refresh();
            console.log("Applying new access token:", newAccessToken);
            originalConfig.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${newAccessToken}`;
            const newResponse = await axiosPrivate(originalConfig);
            return newResponse;

          } catch (error) {
            throw new Error (error);
          }
        }
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    );

    return () => {
      axiosPrivate.interceptors.request.eject(requestIntercept);
      axiosPrivate.interceptors.response.eject(responseIntercept);
    };
  }, [refresh]);

  return axiosPrivate;
}
```